# Why is my "to" prop in my Link of my React app undefined?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

The first code block is my parent component

```
  const [articleState, setArticles] = useState({
    articles: [],
    isFetching: false
  });
  useEffect(() => {
        const url = ---MYURL---;
        const fetchArticles = async () => {
          try {
            setArticles({ articles: articleState.articles, isFetching: true });
            const response = await fetch(url);
            const data = await response.json();
            setArticles({ articles: data.response.docs, isFetching: false });
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            setArticles({ articles: articleState.articles, isFetching: false });
          }
        };
        fetchArticles();
        //eslint-disable-next-line
      }, []);
```

In render, I pass in articles array from state

```
<Articles articles={articleState.articles} loading={articleState.isFetching} />
```

The array passed down to the component as articles in the code block below.

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";    
    const Articles = ({ articles, loading }) => {
          if (loading) return <h2>loading...</h2>;
          return (
            <ul>
              {articles.length !== 0
                ? articles.map((article, index) => (
                    <li
                      key={`${index}__${article.print_section}__${article.print_page}__${article._id}`}
                    >
                      <Link path={`/${article.headline.main}`}>
                        {article.headline.main}
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                  ))
                : null}
            </ul>
          );
        };
```

The article.headline.main in the child renders fine but for the to prop in Link,
I get an undefined error in the console.

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `to` is marked as required in `Link`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

Comment: In your `Link` element you only talk about `path`, not `to`?

Comment: Yes the path. I am sorry.

Comment: It really helps to read the messages before actually asking a question :)

Comment: Appreciate your help. Thx :) I spent half an hour around other possibilities!

Answer (score 1):

The 'path' attribute should be 'to'.

```
<Link to={`/${article.headline.main}`}>
       {article.headline.main}
</Link>
```

Always read the docs before using a new library [React Router Docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start).